# AngularJS - $interpolate - Best way to add additional calculation logic

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, expression, string-interpolation

I've got the following code snippet (see below)

Whats the recommended way to add additional logic to the `$interpolate` string?

e.g I want to add `tax` to the amount.

```
{{amount + (amount / 100 * tax) | currency}}
```

instead of:

```
{{amount | currency}}
```

The problem is that this just appends the value to to the string.

How can I tell Angular that i want to work with numbers?

```
 .directive("evalExpression2", function ($parse, $interpolate) {
                var expressionFn = $parse("total | currency");
                var interpolationFn = $interpolate("The total is: {{amount | currency}}");
                return {
                    scope: {
                        amount: "=amount",
                        tax: "=tax",
                    },
                    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                        scope.$watch("amount", function (newValue) {
                            var localData = {
                                total: Number(newValue)
                                + (Number(newValue) * (Number(scope.tax) / 100))
                            }
                            //element.text(expressionFn(scope, localData));
                            element.text(interpolationFn(scope));
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: can you post a plunk to see what you're refering to?

Comment: `{{amount + (amount / 100 * tax) | currency}}` - If I used this expression with an input value of 10, the result is 101$ - the 10% of 10 are just concatenated to the original value => (10 + 1)  = 101. i guess there must be an easy way to tell Angular that I want to work with numbers? `Number()` doesn't work in the expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parentheses around the whole calculation:

```
{{ (amount + (amount / 100 * tax)  ) | currency }}
```

to avoid the `|` operator having precedence over the `+` operator.

**References**

- [Operator precedence - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)
- [Arithmetic operators - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators)